# How do I specify the XAML that's used in a cell template to only execute when the tooltip appears?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a user control that displays people's first and last names, the agency they're associated with and other items in a DataGrid. And most important for the purposes of this discussion, is the last 4 digits of their social security number. We encrypt the SSN, so to show the SSN I've got to decrypt it. However, my colleague who wrote the encryption/decryption code and tested it says that the testing he did resulted in the code running 45 minutes against all the data we have on people. Obviously, no one is going to wait around for a user control to come up if it takes 45 minutes to render the data grid.

So, my boss asked me to place some text in an SSN column saying that it's Hidden, then when the user hovers their mouse over the control it will pop a tooltip up showing the last 4 of the SSN. At first, I thought this would be easy to do, but then I realized that when I've done this in the past, I was retrieving all the data, then showing what wasn't revealed in a tooltip. I can't do that. So, how do I make it so that when the tooltip pops up, only then will it retrieve the SSN for the given ID, then show the last 4 of the SSN?

Here's what I have currently, first the style I created for the tooltip:

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="DelayToolTip">
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.Placement" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="1000" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="10000" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Here's the XAML I have for the datagrid's columns:

```xml
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Agency Name" Binding="{Binding Agency.AgencyName}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Operator #" Binding="{Binding PersonnelCertifications[0].CertIdentifier}" />
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="SSN">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="Hidden"
                           Foreground="DarkOrange"
                           Background="Aquamarine"
                           Margin="3,1"
                           Style="{StaticResource DelayToolTip}"
                           Padding="3">
                    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="SSN: "
                                       FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Currently it shows the ID value. That ID value is what I need to use to call a stored procedure my colleague wrote, to decrypt the SSN.

I'm working with VS 2019, .NET 4.5.2

Comment: there is a [ToolTip.Opened](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tooltip.opened?view=net-5.0) event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example handle the `Loaded` event for the `TextBlock` in the `Tooltip` something like this:

```
private async void TextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock textBlock = (TextBlock)sender;
    int id = (textBlock.DataContext as Person)?.ID;
    string ssn = await Task.Run(() => { /*call SP and return the SSN here...*/ });
    textBlock.Text = ssn;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="Hidden"
               Foreground="DarkOrange"
               Background="Aquamarine"
               Margin="3,1"
               Style="{StaticResource DelayToolTip}"
               Padding="3">
        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="SSN: " FontWeight="Bold" />
                <TextBlock Text="Loading...." Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded" />
            </StackPanel>
        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```